# From a raster (rasterio) to a geopanda at a polygon level

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio

I'm currently working in a project that makes use of 2 datasets:

1. A raster (geotiff) of nightlight intensity (only one band).
2. A geopanda, where its geometries are polygons/multi-polygons

My objective is to assign to each polygon (row) of the geopanda the average value of the nightlight intensity which are "inside" the polygon.

The crs's are both well set up (I have ploted both), but I'm a bit at a loss as to how to move forward. I have tried to mask the raster, but even so, I still don't understand how to move from there.

Is there are way to do something like a spatial join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [rasterstats.zonal_stats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#zonal-statistics):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

rasterfile = r"/home/bera/GIS/data/nh/2021/Jamtland/nh_23_Jamtlands_lan_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff/nh_68_3.tif"
df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/my_sample.shp")

df["mean_raster_val"] = [x["mean"] for x in zonal_stats(vectors=df["geometry"], raster=rasterfile, stats="mean")] #zonal stats is returning a dictionary of each selected stats, extract the mean.

# df.head()
#       id  ...  mean_raster_val
# 0  54937  ...       735.265224
# 1  55606  ...       882.286165
# 2  55632  ...       742.610002
# 3  55633  ...       746.135290
# 4  55634  ...       767.089377
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too much data to process, I second the answer by BERA using rasterstats.zonalstats.

If the performance is not satisfactory for your use case, you might want to consider using pyqgis. The API isn't as clean, but based on some [benchmarks](https://github.com/geofileops/geobenchmark?tab=readme-ov-file#zonalstats) I did a while ago, it is about 10 times as fast.

Some Sample code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import qgis.core
import qgis.analysis

# Init app
qgs = qgis.core.QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Reads the input file
vlayer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer(str(vector_path), vector_path.stem, "ogr")

# Calculates zonal stats with raster
raster = qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer(str(raster_path))
stats = (
    qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics.Count
    | qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics.Sum
    | qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics.Mean
)
zoneStats = qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics(
    vlayer,
    raster,
    stats=stats,
    rasterBand=1,
)
zoneStats.calculateStatistics(None)

columns = [f.name() for f in vlayer.fields()] + ["geometry"]
# columns_types = [f.typeName() for f in vlayer.fields()]
data = [
    dict(zip(columns, f.attributes() + [f.geometry().asWkt()]))
    for f in vlayer.getFeatures()
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df["geometry"] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df["geometry"])
stats = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry="geometry", crs=vlayer.crs().toWkt()
)
del vlayer

print(stats)
```